# update json property value using loop

Tags: javascript, json, loops

```
[{id:1,price:10},{id:2,price:20}]
```

How can I update the price to 200 for array of objects of id `2`?

```
var obj = [{id:1,price:10},{id:2,price:20}];
for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
        if(obj[i].id == 2){
          //what to do here?
        }
      }
```

I can proceed with push and splice etc but the challenge is to keep the position too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or shorter with [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
var obj = [{ id: 1, price: 10 }, { id: 2, price: 20 }];

obj.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.id === 2) {
        a.price = 200;
    }
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: this is cleaner, is forEach supported in all browser?

Comment: please have a look here: [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
obj[i].price = 200;
break;
```

The break will prevent you to continue looping over all the items (since you found the one you were searching for).

Comment: I don't think a loop would even be needed with an object literal just to access a property...

Comment: does this same with return false?

Answer (score 0):

```
[{id:1,price:10},{id:2,price:20}].forEach(function(a){ (a.id===2) ? a.price=200 : a});
```